# Awareness and opinion of Russians on USSR ethnicity-based population transfers

Tags: russian-federation, public-opinion, discrimination

I'd heard about the [deportation of the Crimean tatars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deportation_of_the_Crimean_Tatars) for the first time from the Eurovision song [1944](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1944_(song)), which is one of many [population transfers in the Soviet Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_transfer_in_the_Soviet_Union).

How aware are Russian people about population transfer in the Soviet Union in general, and what opinion do they have about such actions?

Comment: Asking for "opinion" is, unsurprisingly, "opinion-based". Please consider re-writing the title and 2nd paragraph.

Comment: @bytebuster me asking "what do you think about X" would be opinion based, but "what does group X think about Y" is not.

Comment: Example of a similar question that got a referenced answer: http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9521/what-do-americans-nowadays-think-about-wwii-internment

Comment: *"…answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise"*; I guess, it speaks for itself. This Q attracts bad answers. And, if we're unlucky enough, — for *very bad* answers, like the existing one.

Comment: @bytebuster the poster of that answer has asked you for clarification of what's wrong with his answer. Why haven't you answered him?

Comment: @bytebuster No, it is not. If there is polls stating what people's opinions were clearly, then asking for an opinion is not opinion based.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Psychology not politics.

Answer (score 2):

In the last years of Soviet Union (and in modern Russia too) there was quite much information available on these topics. I say, much more than disinterested people in the West may and/or want to know.

Talking of Crimean Tatars, that deportation was only one of the series which took place after WW2. Think of [Expulsion of Germans from Czechoslovakia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expulsion_of_Germans_from_Czechoslovakia), or [Expulsion of Ukrainians from Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expulsion_of_Ukrainians_from_Poland_to_the_Soviet_Union).

Crimean Tatars were among strongest supporters of Nazi regime in occupied territories of SU. So that deportation was considered as a kind of punishment at that time; quite in line with other similar actions which took place after WW2.

Of course, such an indiscriminate measure isn't admissible by any modern standards. In 1989 the Supreme Council of Soviet Union recognized it as unlawful and criminal.

But if you ask about people's opinion in modern Russia, I'd say that there are still different points of view. That is some people still argue that "they fully deserved this". I don't think that the latter opinion is really predominant, yet it seems to have more than just marginal support.

Comment: @bytebuster What is exactly "opinionated declaration"? The level of Nazi support among Crimean tatars? Or the fact that some Russian people still justify the deportation? Or the fact that Soviet and Russian governments condemned the latter?